# DefaultTableModel, add row, dynamic number of columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

As above, I don't know how many columns will be in a row, so obviously I'm running into issues with the `String[]` array. There will be at least 2 columns - that's a given.

How do I work around this limitation?

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0,1+queryResult.size());



Object[] row = {t.getDate(),'some data'};

tableModel.addRow(row);

view.getPriceHistoryTable().setModel(tableModel);
```

but if queryResult.size() is bigger than 1 then instead I want to do:

```
Object[] row = {t.getDate(),'some data','more data'};

tableModel.addRow(row);

view.getPriceHistoryTable().setModel(tableModel);
```

and so on...

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your queryResult.size() should tell you the number of columns. Or you can use the table.getColumnCount() method.

Comment: @camickr added explanation

Comment: Why can't you create the model with a default number of columns, and then use `.addColumn()` to add the additional column if the data so indicates?

Comment: Still don't understand the problem. Where does "some data" and "more data" come from. If you know how many pieces of data you have you just add the data to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of an array doesn't have to be a compile time constant:

```
int colCount = 1 + queryResult.size();

String[] row = new String[colCount];
row[0] = t.getDate();

for(int i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
    row[i] = "some data"; // or get data from somewhere else
}

tableModel.addRow(row);
```

Comment: If this is the answer then don't use an Array. Just use a Vector and the addElement() method to add items to the Vector. The DefaultTableModel will convert the Array to a Vector anyway, so using the Vector would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the column model through your JTable object and have all information about your columns

```
int cols = table.getColumnCount();
```

Using your model, you can set the number of rows and columns this way

```
model.setRowCount(rows); 
model.setColumnCount(cols);
```

So you can set dynamically your number of rows and columns according to your query results

Comment: I know that but it doesn't help me with my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i < 1+queryResult.size(); i++)
    model.addColumn(i+1); // i+1 will be the header name for each column
```

do this initially, then you can add your rows